# Wrong time stamp using docker container: time zone setting has no effect

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

The technology stack is Spring Boot 2.2.5.RELEASE, JPA with Hibernate, Java 8, MySQL 5.7.31.
There are database fields containing a timestamp like 2020-11-26 14:00, so without a time zone.

Running the Spring Boot application and the MySQL database on Windows (without any docker involvement), there is no issue.

However the timestamp (after reading from the database) has a wrong value (2020-11-26 13:00) when the Spring Boot application runs on macOS (directy) and the MySQL database inside a docker container (I use this one: https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql -> 5.7.31).
I could solve this by setting the time zone in the application.properties:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://${MYSQL_HOST:localhost}:3306/<mydb>?serverTimezone=Europe/Berlin&sessionVariables=sql_mode='...
```

I also run the application in a pipeline (gitlab.com) with both Spring Boot and the MySQL database in a docker container. To be more specific they run in separate containers. Now the issue with the wrong timestamp occurs again. The time zone set via spring.datasource.url seems to have no effect.

Answer (score 1):

The time zone of the docker container was not correctly set.

```
variables:
  TZ: "Europe/Berlin"
```

in *.gitlab-ci.yml* does the trick.